# Need help to find out why Websphere Application Server has many .lck files

Tags: websphere

The file names seesm to point to our WAS data sources. However, we're not sure what is creating them and why there are so many. The servers didn't seem to crash. Why is WAS 6.1.0.23 creating these andy why aren't they being cleaned?

There are many files like these, with some going up to xxx.43.lck
 DWSqlLog0.0.lck
 DWSqlLog0.0
 TritonSqlLog0.0.lck
 TritonSqlLog0.0
 JTSqlLog0.0
 JTSqlLog0.1
 JTSqlLog0.3
 JTSqlLog0.2
 JTSqlLog0.4.lck
 JTSqlLog0.4
 JTSqlLog0.3.lck
 JTSqlLog0.2.lck
 JTSqlLog0.1.lck
 JTSqlLog0.0.lck

Answer (score 0):

WAS uses JDK Logging and JDK logger creates such files with extension .0,.1 etc along with the .lck file so that the WAS runtime has a lock to these files that it writes to.

Cheers
Manglu

Comment: Hello, I figured out my problem on why it creates so many files. Looks like someone added log names and sql trace to Finest in the data sources custom properties. Thanks.